# Updating the Fields in the JSON_ARRAY Mysql 8.0

Tags: mysql, sql, json, mysql-workbench, mysql-8.0

Here is my scenario, I want to update the hourly_rate for the `BOB` to 600. How to extract the hourly_rate from the json_array mentioned below for the specific user `BOB`.

```
@data = [{
 "Subject": "Maths",
 "type": "paid",
 "tutor": "MARY",
 "hourly_rate": "500"
},
{
 "Subject": "Maths",
 "type": "paid",
 "tutor": "BOB",
 "hourly_rate": "700"
}]
```

Can I use `JSON_SEARCH()` to get the index by using `Where` Clause.

example:

```
  "Select JSON_SET(@data,'$[*].hourly_rate', 600) Where 'Subject' = Maths and 'tutor' = 'BOB'";
```

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html

Comment: @Rahul Reddy Answered and done :)

Comment: I'm curious, why did you use JSON for this array of documents that are all the same, instead of storing the data as rows in a table with normal columns? Then it would be simple to set the `hourly_rate` or any other individual column, by updating it on a single row.

Comment: The Json Column Which I am using will contain the different subjects and different types (Paid and free). Here each Row contains coaching institute information. So Instead of having `coaching_institute_id` floating around other tables. I kind of kept Columns in de-normalized state. and Main reason is We have a plan of moving into NoSQL in near future and from research having de-normalized structure makes the work easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this working. But I had to use a `view` in order to get cleaner code.

My answer is based on this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51563616/1688441

---

### Update Query

Fiddle @ https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7MnPYEJW2uiGYaPhSSjtKa/1

```
UPDATE test
  INNER JOIN getJsonArray ON getJsonArray.tutor = 'BOB'
SET test =
  JSON_REPLACE(
    test,
    CONCAT('$[', getJsonArray.rowid - 1, '].hourly_rate'), 600);

select * from test;
```

---

### Ddl

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `test` json DEFAULT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `test` (`test`)
VALUES ('[{
 "Subject": "Maths",
 "type": "paid",
 "tutor": "MARY",
 "hourly_rate": "500"
},
{
 "Subject": "Maths",
 "type": "paid",
 "tutor": "BOB",
 "hourly_rate": "700"
}]');

create view getJsonArray as    
select data.* 
from   test, json_table(
  test,
         "$[*]"
         COLUMNS(
          rowid FOR ORDINALITY,
            Subject VARCHAR(100) PATH "$.Subject" DEFAULT '111' ON EMPTY DEFAULT '999' ON ERROR,
            type VARCHAR(100) PATH "$.type" DEFAULT '111' ON EMPTY DEFAULT '999' ON ERROR,
            tutor VARCHAR(100) PATH "$.tutor" DEFAULT '111' ON EMPTY DEFAULT '999' ON ERROR,
            hourly_rate JSON PATH "$.hourly_rate" DEFAULT '{"x": 333}' ON EMPTY
         )
       ) data
      ;
```

Comment: Working !! Thanks

Comment: @Rahul Reddy Do change the default values in the `getJsonArray` view. There are some `ON EMPTY` and `ON ERROR`